# SSAS how to turn the following SQL script into MDX?

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I want to calculate the daily number of children as a measure in SSAS. The logic should be written in SQL as follows:

```
Select Count(distinct ChildID)
From Child
Group by CurrentDate
```

How could I translate this script into MDX for calculation? I'm new to SSAS.

Comment: Has the date field been made into a dimension ?

Comment: Yes, the CurrentDate is also a dimension.

Comment: ohoh  I see your point. So if CurrentDate is a dimension, then I only need to count distinct ChildID, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot on how your dimensions are set up but shooting from the hip you could set up a measure that is a count of childid.  To do that in SSAS under the cube structure create a new measure and select `count` under the `usage` property and the proper table under the `source table`.  You could call this measure Child Count or something like that.

With a distinct child count measure set up the MDX would be something like this:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ [Measures].[Child Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
{ ([Dim Child].[CurrentDate].[CurrentDate].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM [Your Cube]
```